# Spring MVC AccessDeniedException 500 error received instead of custom 401 error for @PreAuthorized unauth requests

Tags: java, spring, security, model-view-controller, authorization

I'm writing a Java Spring MVC 4 REST app that'll sit between front-end devices (websites, mobile apps, etc) and a database. I have code below that will create a new session for each request (since REST is stateless), look at the Authorization header of the request, and will confirm the token is valid and request authenticated.

When a user is requesting a secure method without a valid token, I'm looking to redirect unauthorized requests from a 500 Access Is Denied message to a 401 Unauthorized message.

This is what I have so far.

AccessDeniedHandler:

```
public class Unauthorized401AccessDeniedHandler implements AccessDeniedHandler {
    @Override
    public void handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                       AccessDeniedException accessDeniedException)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        response.setStatus(401);
    }
}
```

WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedHandler(new Unauthorized401AccessDeniedHandler());

    }
}
```

Filter:

```
public class SecurityFilter implements Filter {
    final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SecurityFilter.class);

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,
                         FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();

        String requestUri = request.getRequestURI();

        session.invalidate();
        SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();

        session = request.getSession(true); // create a new session
        SecurityContext ctx = SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext();


        boolean isLoggedIn = false;

        String token = null;
        String authorizationHeader = request.getHeader("authorization");
        if(authorizationHeader != null && authorizationHeader.startsWith("bearer")) {
            String encryptedToken = authorizationHeader.split(" ")[1];
            token = StringUtils.newStringUtf8(Base64.decodeBase64(encryptedToken));

            // confirm user is logged in and authorized here TBD

            isLoggedIn = true;
        }

        PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken authentication = null;
        if(isLoggedIn) {
            SessionCredentialsModel authRequestModel = new SessionCredentialsModel();
            authRequestModel.employeeId = 323;
            authRequestModel.firstName = "Danny";
            authRequestModel.lastName = "Boy";
            authRequestModel.token = "this_is_a_test_token";

            authentication = new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken(authRequestModel, token);
        } else {
            authentication = new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken(new SessionCredentialsModel(), null);
        }

        authentication.setAuthenticated(true);
        ctx.setAuthentication(authentication);

        SecurityContextHolder.setContext(ctx);
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }
```

Security Model (aka Security Context Principal):

```
public class SessionCredentialsModel {
    public int employeeId;
    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;
    public String token;

    public boolean isAuthenticated() {
        if(employeeId > 0 && token != null) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

and finally the controller:

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @PreAuthorize("principal.isAuthenticated()")
    public ResponseEntity<LoginResponseModel> create() {
        LoginResponseModel responseModel = new LoginResponseModel();
        responseModel.statusCode = 55;
        responseModel.token = "authorized model worked!";

        return new ResponseEntity<LoginResponseModel>(responseModel, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

When I run the method without an Authorization header I get this error (instead of the error I'm looking to get):

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied

type Exception report

message Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    net.pacificentertainment.middletier.app.security.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:73)
root cause

org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:84)
    org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:233)
    org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:65)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:656)
    net.pacificentertainment.middletier.app.controllers.EmployeeController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b6765b64.create(<generated>)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    net.pacificentertainment.middletier.app.security.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:73)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/8.0.43 logs.

Apache Tomcat/8.0.43
```

I'm at a loss to figure out why I can't get the unauthorized request to return a 401 -- or any other status code other than a 500.

What do you think?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

OK guys, wasn't able to get any help from the community BUT I did find a solution -- although it's not a direct solution.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class SecurityExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler({AccessDeniedException.class})
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleAccessDeniedException(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
        if(ex.getMessage().toLowerCase().indexOf("access is denied") > -1) {
            return new ResponseEntity<Object>("Unauthorized Access", new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(ex.getMessage(), new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

This new file in my app will allow me to control what happens during an exception. Now I can just manually inspect the problem to see if it was "access is denied" and then redirect to 401 which DOES WORK. The problem above was that the code to redirect to the 401 wasn't ever being hit. This code DOES get executed.

Again, this isn't a direct solution as we're manipulating a different piece of Spring MVC and kind of hacking default behavior to get it to work.

If anyone has a more elegant solution, please do post.

Comment: Tried to edit, but 'edit queue is fulle' ... so comment here.  The argument [WebRequest request] is not used in this code.

Answer (score 2):

This error runs because the **AuthenticationEntryPoint** of java could override or map the error with 500 status.

You can solve this with the next code implemented in

```
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler implements AuthenticationEntryPoint  {

 @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException ) throws IOException, ServletException {    
      response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
      response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
      response.getOutputStream().println("{ \"error\": \"" + authException.getMessage() + "\" }");
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(value = { AccessDeniedException.class })
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AccessDeniedException ex ) throws IOException {
      response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
      response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
      response.getOutputStream().println("{ \"error\": \"" + ex.getMessage() + "\" }");
    }
```

With this code you could catch the AccessDeniedException, wich is throws by @PreAuthorize annotacion

Answer (score 1):

I also got a HTTP 500 where I expected a 403. For me it was the result of misconfiguration of Spring Security in Spring 5. I configured the filter chain to permit all requests for the `/pages` endpoint.

```
http.csrf().disable()
               .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(preAuthFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/pages/**", "/sessions/").permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();
```

At the same time I added a `@PreAuthorize` annotation on the same `/pages` endpoint.

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ORG_ADMIN')")
@GetMapping("/pages/{uniqueUrlName}")
public ResponseEntity<Page> page(@PathVariable("uniqueUrlName") String uniqueUrlName) {
    // implementation here
}
```

This causes `org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter` to be skipped and the `AccessDeniedException` is then handled as a regular application exception, in my case by a `@ExceptionHandler` method in a `@ControllerAdvice` class.

Removing the `permitAll()` config resolved the issue. I now see a 403 when hitting the endpoint with an unauthenticated request.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're not using Spring Boot - Might it be that you did not register the `springSecurityFilterChain` with the container?

The stack trace does not show any Spring Security filters getting called. Your custom `AccessDeniedHandler` would get called in the `ExceptionTranslationFilter` that resides in the `springSecurityFilterChain`. But it seems like your method security interceptor is throwing an `AccessDeniedException` that isn't getting caught anywhere.

Check out the [reference guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#abstractsecuritywebapplicationinitializer).