# What should @PreAuthorize do?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I have simple `crud` with `spring-mcv` and `spring-security`.

Everything its up and running

`spring-security.xml`

```
<b:bean id="handlerWeb1" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler">
    <b:property name="permissionEvaluator" ref="permissionEvaluator"/>
</b:bean>
<b:bean id="handlerMethod2" class="org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler">
    <b:property name="permissionEvaluator" ref="permissionEvaluator"/>
</b:bean>

<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled">
    <expression-handler ref="handlerMethod2"/>
</global-method-security>

<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" >
    <expression-handler ref="handlerWeb1" />
    ...
</http>
```

The logger

```
INFO: Using bean 'handlerWeb1' as web SecurityExpressionHandler implementation
INFO: Using bean 'handlerMethod2' as method ExpressionHandler implementation
```

When the fallow methodo is executed:

```
@RequestMapping("/page")
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission('page','list')")
public ModelAndView pages() {

    return modelAndView( ... ));
}
```

If `hasPermission('page','list')==true` there is no problem.

If `hasPermission('page','list')==false` the methodo still render the `view` but the `vatiables` passed tto de `view` are empty.

Ask:
When `hasPermission('page','list')==false`, what should happen?

a) redirect to 403

b) render the view with variable empty.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40847301/spring-security-preauthorize-works-only-together-with-requestmapping

Comment: This to the trick [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43554489/spring-mvc-accessdeniedexception-500-error-received-instead-of-custom-401-error#answer-43618938](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43554489/spring-mvc-accessdeniedexception-500-error-received-instead-of-custom-401-error#answer-43618938)